# Menu desplegable, no se despliega

Tags: html, bootstrap-5

Estoy realizando una página web responsive y me estoy volviendo loco pues no encuentro el modo de hacer que se despliegue mi barra de menu cuando achico la pantalla, he calcado mi codigo de otra página web que habia realizado anteriormente donde si que me funcionaba dicha caracteristica, pero aqui ahora no ¿sabeis que es lo que ocurre? tengo puesto el script y todo, pero no me responde. Dudo que el fallo radique en el lugar donde este situado el script, pues en la otra página que tengo, practicamente es la misma estructura, con el mismo nav, y no me da ningún tipo de problema extraño.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="assets/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/site.css">
    <title>Julian Alfred Pankratz | INICIO</title>
</head>

<body id="inicio">
    <header class="menu">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <img src="assets/img/logo.jpg" alt="logo"
                    class="d-inline-block align-text-top rounded-circle logo-menu">
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup"
                    aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
                    <div class="navbar-nav">
                        <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Inicio</a>
                        <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Servicios</a>
                        <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Biografia</a>
                        <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Contacto</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <div id="my-row-01" class="my-row">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12 col-md-7"></div>
                <div class="col-12 col-md-5"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="my-row-02" class="my-row">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12"></div>
                <div class="col col-sm-6 col-md-3"></div>
                <div class="col col-sm-6 col-md-3"></div>
                <div class="col col-sm-6 col-md-3"></div>
                <div class="col col-sm-6 col-md-3"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="my-row-03" class="my-row">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12 col-md-5"></div>
                <div class="col-12 col-md-7"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="my-row-04" class="my-row">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12 col-md-6"></div>
                <div class="col-12 col-md-6"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="my-row-05" class="my-row">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12 col-md-7"></div>
                <div class="col-12 col-md-5"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="my-row-06" class="my-row">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12"></div>
                <div class="col col-sm-6 col-md-3"></div>
                <div class="col col-sm-6 col-md-3"></div>
                <div class="col col-sm-6 col-md-3"></div>
                <div class="col col-sm-6 col-md-3"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="my-row-07" class="my-row">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12 col-md-5"></div>
                <div class="col-12 col-md-7"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="my-row-08" class="my-row">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12 col-md-7"></div>
                <div class="col-12 col-md-5"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="my-row-09" class="my-row">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12 col-md-4"></div>
                <div class="col-12 col-md-8"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="my-row-10" class="my-row">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12 col-md-5"></div>
                <div class="col-12 col-md-7"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <footer>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12"></div>
                <div class="col col-sm-6 col-md-3"></div>
                <div class="col col-sm-6 col-md-3"></div>
                <div class="col col-sm-6 col-md-3"></div>
                <div class="col col-sm-6 col-md-3"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cambia todos los atributos `data-` por `data-bs-` pues estas usando bootstrap 5 y es uno de los cambios descritos en la migración desde anteriores versiones de bootstrap.

[En la sección de Javascript de su página encontrarás el cambio](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/migration/#javascript)

Comment: me sirvió. Perdón por lo obvio de esta pregunta; todavía estoy comenzando.

Comment: No te preocupes, todos hemos empezado alguna vez :-) Y no es tan obvio, muchos comenten el mismo error mezclando cosas de distintas versiones de bootstrap.