# ¿Por qué no puedo abrir un modal en mi proyecto de Laravel -vue.js?

Tags: javascript, php, css, laravel, vue.js

Buen día, estoy haciendo un CRUD en Laravel 8 con Vuejs. En un componente que he creado estoy incorporando un modal para poder tener un formulario de "nuevo registro", sin embargo, este modal no abre.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Cabe resaltar que he seguido estos pasos en el proyecto:**

1. Luego de creado el proyecto pasé a ejecutar "composer require laravel/ui"
2. También, creé un scaffolding de autenticación con el comando "php artisan ui vue --auth"
3. Después, para instalar todas las dependencias, pasé a ejecutar "npm install".
4. Finalmente, "npm run dev" para compilar y que se creen las carpetas "JS" y "CSS" en la raíz "public" del proyecto de Laravel.

**Alguna solución a este problema del modal de Bootstrap y por qué no abre? Agradecería alguna respuesta**

Adjunto aquí la imagen en donde estoy incorporando el modal simple en el componente de vue:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El código va como texto por favor, no como imagen.

Comment: No todos pueden visualizar las imágenes: pon el código _como texto, con formato_.

Comment: Ok, aunque es ridículo que un simple modal vaya como código en esta pregunta en específico.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si estas usando [**bootstrap 5**](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/getting-started/introduction/) cambia **todos** los atributos `data-` por `data-bs-`  porque es uno de los cambios descritos en la migración desde anteriores versiones de bootstrap.

[En la sección de Javascript de su página encontrarás el cambio](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/migration/#javascript)

Si no lo haces no solo los modales no te van a funcionar, sino tampoco los *dropdowns*, etc.

Una pregunta parecida la respondí [aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/506039/menu-desplegable-no-se-despliega/506041#506041).

Comment: Gracias, era la versión de Bootstrap.